# Magento 2 knockout Select options observable returning previous value

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.2.2

I have Created custom component with select drop down when I select an option and alert the select option it spits out :

```
 function observable() {
          if (arguments.length > 0) {
             // Write

             // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
        if (observable.isDifferent(_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
            observable.valueWillMutate();
            _latestValue = arguments[0];
            if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
            observable.valueHasMutated();
        }
        return this; // Permits chained assignments
    }
    else {
        // Read
        ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation
        return _latestValue;
    }
}
```

I have :

> availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['--Please Select--', 'France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
>               chosenCountries : ko.observableArray(['--Please Select--']),

I can display just fine like so:

```
<span data-bind="text: chosenCountries"></span>
```

I can push from my function just fine like so:

> this.availableCountries.push('New item')

BUT I CAN'T from my function

> alert(this.availableCurrencies)

or

> console.log(this.availableCurrencies)

it spits the the observable  function above!

UPADTE: I did console.log(this.availableCurrencies._latestValue); and it gives me the previous value how to get currnetValue?

Full js component :

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'ko'
    ],
    function (Component, $, stepNavigator, quote, ko) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/view/summary/country'
            },
            availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['--Please Select--', 'France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
            chosenCountries : ko.observableArray(['--Please Select--']),
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                return this;
            },
            getCountry:function (data, event) {
                console.log(this.chosenCoutries());
            }

        });
    }
);
```

and country.html:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="event:{ change: getCountry}, options: availableCountries, selectedOptions: chosenCountries"></select>
    <span data-bind="text: chosenCountries"></span>

</div>
```

[image]
[image]
Anyone nay help please!Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add parenthesis like so:

```
console.log(this.availableCurrencies());
```

Without the parenthesis you will only log the function, and to set the observable you add content inside the parentheis like this:

```
this.testObservable('New value');
```

Comment: Thank's The same this tried with parentheses it gives me the previous value how do i get the current ?

Comment: `this.availableCurrencies()` always should be the current, if you're getting the wrong value it's usually when you're setting the value outside of KO like `this.availableCurrencies = whatever`. I think the issue is around the usage of `_latestValue` - As far as I'm aware you shouldn't really use this. 

All my uses have been:
- `this.getObservableTest();`
- `this.setObservableTest(newValue);`

Comment: It doesn't seen to give the current value I've update with full code perhaps you can spot something worng?

Comment: There is a typo here - `console.log(this.chosenCoutries());`. This should be `console.log(this.chosenCountries());`. Does fixing that change anything?

Comment: No I've made typo when editing the question !

Comment: I've manage to get the current value by adding timeout,@Ben Crook It works if I add a timeout: setTimeout(function(){ console.log(data. chosenCountries()); }, 1000);  Thank's for you help!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure to get the newly selected value instead of the previous value you have to modify your knockout template:

```html
<select data-bind="event:{ input: getCountry}, valueUpdate: 'input', options: availableCountries, selectedOptions: chosenCountries"></select>
```

This is because the `getCountry` function was called before the `chosenCountries`  observable was updated with the new value. This is the default behaviour of the change event in Knockout.js. With the `input` change event it works as expected.